# Parenthesis around AND OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, parentheses

I needed some help in making sure I am using my parenthesis correctly around AND OR statements in SQL SERVER.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Table
WHERE yearmonth = 201404
 AND (HasA = 1 OR HasB = 1 OR hasC = 1)
 AND (HasAX = 10 OR HasBX = 10 OR HasCX = 10)
```

When I have my parenthesis like above my second AND line of code, it also pulls out other values like example HasCX= 23.

Ironically this line of code works well:

```
AND (HasA = 1 OR HasB = 1 OR hasC = 1)
```

How should I write my parenthesis around this ?

```
AND (HasAX = 10 OR HasBX = 10 OR HasCX = 10)
```

It should only pull out data for where the condition is met with 10.

Comment: ((HasA=1 OR HasB=1 OR hasC=1) AND( HasAX=10 OR HasBX=10 OR HasCX=10))

Comment: What values are in `HasAX and HasBX` for `HasCX= 23`?

Comment: The rule is: without parenthesis, AND is taken care of before OR.

Comment: This question would probably be much clearer with some sample data and your expected results (including some sample data that currently doesn't work correctly with your given attempt)

Comment: It does not work. It still pulls out values other than 10. I have even tried ((HasA=1 OR HasB=1 OR hasC=1) AND( HasAX=10) OR (HasBX=10) OR (HasCX=10))) .

Comment: @dataaddicted, can you describe waht are you want to pull from database ?

Comment: I solved the problem by doing a DELETE FROM with a WHERE conditions in the final step of extraction.

Comment: That doesn't sound right

Comment: It doesnt reqiure a delete operation to solve the problem.

Comment: In general, if you have two AND conditions like the ones I have in my post, where should the parentheses go?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Better yet, set up a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for your query, a cleaner way to write the logic is to use `in`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Table
WHERE yearmonth = 201404 AND
      1 IN (HasA, HasB, HasC) AND
      10 IN (HasAX, HasBX, HaxCX)
```

I suspect that what you really want is:

```
WHERE yearmonth = 201404 AND
      ((HasA = 1 AND HasAZ = 10) OR
       (HasB = 1 AND HasBZ = 10) OR
       (HasC = 1 AND HasCZ = 10)
      )
```

Alternatively, you might want all of these connected by `AND` and not `OR`.

Comment: Thank you, however it is still giving my other products. Let me explain. I have the HasA OR HasB OR HasC as a way  pull out customers that have either one of the products. I cannot use AND after each HasA and HasB and HasC as it will pull out all customers that had all three products.  The selection of HasAZ and so is because they have to be on a specific platform, let's say Fiber. Even with your code, It still is picking out coax.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is right. Check your data. A row can have HasCx=23 but also have HasBX=1.